# Autodesk Forge: How to get started with creating a configurator

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am extremely new to Web Development. I'm trying to create a configurator application that can load a part into the viewer, have a menu to modify its dimensions, and update the viewer. So far, I developed a basic Web Application that can create a bucket, upload a file, translate it, and load it into the viewer following this tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview

Now, I would like to request custom dimensions from the user and update the file with those dimensions. I'm not sure how I can get started with this as I have very little knowledge on the subject. This is the link I found for modifying models: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels

What would be the basic steps to incorporate the modify models code to [this](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-walkthrough-online.viewer)? Also, would I need to download AutoCAD/ Inventor/ Revit/ 3ds max to run or test this code? I'm feeling lost and am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete sample for Inventor: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor

Comment: Would I need to have Autodesk Inventor installed for this? What role would a local instance of AutoCAD/ Inventor/ Revit/ 3ds max play in developing a configurator?

Comment: Having a desktop version of the given product is very useful when creating/modifying the code of your **app bundle**, but not a requirement.
If you're OK with the overhead of uploading your latest code to the Design Automation server each time you modify something, then you can test your code directly there. 
These videos might come useful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CksbjYLvrpg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA82e_XcMrY